# Which data type should I use to store a 11 digit number

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, datatypes

Which data type I should use to store an 11 digit number? It must store '0' as the first digit.

For example, if I store `02421402015`, it must show `02421402015`. I tried using `varchar` and it shows `2421402015`.

Comment: If you store `01234` in a `varchar`, it will show `01234` unless you are doing something else with it (e.g. an implicit conversion to a number in SQL Server, or some assumption by presentation code). Can you show the code that leads to this output? And can you explain why you need to *store* the leading 0 when this is something that is trivial to add to the number at presentation time?

Comment: Can you provide sample code?  If you stored 02421402015 in varchar(11), it would definitely be stored with the leading zero.  It's only when you select it back out and try to convert it to an integer that it will strip the leading zero.

Comment: Please clarify the intended usage of this value. A value that has digits only but allows for leading zeros is _not_ a "number": it is a string of digits. Zipcodes fall into this category as they can have leading zeros. Is the issue only with display the value, or will someone need to filter on `0123`?

Answer (score 14):

I would suggest storing the number as a `BIGINT`, and simply displaying the number the way you want it.

```
DECLARE @Num BIGINT;

SET @Num = 2421402015;

SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(11), REPLICATE('0', 11 - LEN(@Num))) 
    + CONVERT(VARCHAR(11), @Num);
```

As pointed out by [Aaron Bertrand](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/1186/aaron-bertrand) in his comment, it is better performance-wise to not calculate the length of the required string of zeros, and simply truncate the string:

```
SELECT RIGHT(REPLICATE('0', 11) + CONVERT(VARCHAR(11), @Num), 11);
```

For your sample number, the concatenation would result in '000000000002421402015', which would then be right-truncated into 11 digits resulting in:

```
02421402015
```

In fact, as [srutzky](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/30859/srutzky) pointed out, this can be further optimized to:

```
SELECT RIGHT('00000000000' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(11), @Num), 11);
```

If users will pass in values with leading zeros that need to get matched in a `WHERE` clause,  I would convert the search term to an integer first, then use that in the predicate, so an index can be used.

I've written a blog post<sup>1</sup> that details how you can store the number as an integer, while simultaneously providing an elegant method for the number to look like it's being stored in the database with leading zeros.  Check http://www.sqlserver.science/basics/how-do-i-store-a-number-with-leading-zeros/ for the details!  There are several other methods of formatting the leading zeros column, however the [performance of each method varies](http://www.sqlserver.science/performance/same-plan-markedly-different-performance/) quite drastically; the `RIGHT('00000000000' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(11), @Num), 11)` method looks like it's the fastest by far.

---

<sup>1 - My blog post was featured in the [SQL PASS Community Connector News](http://www.sqlpass.org/Community/ConnectorNews/TabId/15340/ArtMID/23897/ArticleID/346/Featured-Blog-Max-Vernon-How-do-I-store-a-number-with-leading-zeros.aspx)</sup>
<sup>2 - [Follow up post](http://www.sqlserver.science/performance/same-plan-markedly-different-performance/) on performance of `FORMATMESSAGE()` function in SQL Server 2012+</sup>

Answer (score 6):

To demonstrate that what you're saying in your question is not true:

```
DECLARE @x TABLE(y VARCHAR(11));

INSERT @x(y) VALUES('02421402015');

SELECT y FROM @x;
```

Results:

```
y
-----------
02421402015
```

You need to tell us more details about what is going on so we can understand your problem better.

But most importantly, you need to consider separating storage from presentation. It is far more efficient to store a number as an `int` (4 bytes) or `bigint` (8 bytes) as opposed to a `varchar(11)` (11 bytes + 2 bytes to indicate length), and you also get built-in validation (so someone can't store `I'm varchar` instead of a number), arithmetic, etc. without implicit or explicit conversion becoming a necessity. A leading `0` for display is trivial to add in your presentation tier, or even in SQL Server at query time if you really must. It is also trivial to add to or remove from incoming search criteria so that you're searching against the right and most efficient data types, using the right parameter type, regardless of what the user thinks they're searching and seeing...